# selectize.js dynamically adding options to selectbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

How to add options to selectize.js using ajax? I saw some questions about same but could not get it to work.

```
$('#select-country-field').selectize({
  valueField: 'country',
  labelField: 'country',
  searchField: 'country',
  options: [],
  load: function(query, callback) {
    if (!query.length) return callback();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ajaxurl.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: query,
        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        },
        success: function(res) {
            callback(res);
        }
    });
  }
})
;
```

how to code ajaxurl.php? it should return data like this

```
[{ country: 'USA'}, {country: 'GB'}, {country: 'FR'}, ... ]
```

Comment: So you're asking how to start to code in php?

Comment: i know to code php, just want to know that json thing

Comment: It's a string.  You return a string from your PHP function: "[{ country: 'USA'}, {country: 'GB'}, {country: 'FR'}, ... ]"